# how to transfer git repository from windows to os x

Tags: git, macos, sourcetree

i'm try to copy repo.rar from windows share drive and add it to sourcetree but sourcetree can't see .git folder and all file in folder is Not Tracked file.

Comment: Don't use rar, use "git bundle"

Comment: Don't use rar, use `git fetch`